# Delete cascade with JPA DSL

Tags: java, jpa

I need to delete an entity with its children entities. Here is my code :

```
public void deleteCascade(Integer entityId) {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaDelete<MyEntity> criteriaDelete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(MyEntity.class);
  Root<MyEntity> myEntity = criteriaDelete.from(MyEntity.class);
  criteriaDelete.where(
          cb.equal(MyEntity.get(MyEntity_.id), entityId)
  );
  em.createQuery(criteriaDelete).executeUpdate();
}
```

This will obviously not work because of orphans. I know 2 solutions which do not statisfy me :

- Manually delete orphans, one request per entity.
- Anotate the entity attributes.

I would actually prefer using a simple parameter somewhere but cannot find if it exists.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you use some more expressions in your where statement, or why don't you use `EntityManager.remove()`? And with _annotate the entity attributes_ you mean `cascade=...`?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Yes, I could use `EntityManager.remove()`, And yes, I mean `cascade = ...`. In order to have the code working, I will use the annotation but I would appreciate if a cleaner method existed.

Comment: I think that `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` (or `CascadeType.ALL`) is the best solution, as it describes the relationship where it belongs to: in the model. Otherwise it is easy to forget to delete the orphans when you (or one of your collaborators) delete a `MyEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1. With two queries:

  1. Delete ALL future orphans (i.e BULK DELETE, not a query per entity).
  2. Delete the entity itself.
- Solution 2: I am not sure it is not the same as your second idea:
  Mark the relationship with [`orphanRemoval=true`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/)

Comment: `orphanRemoval` is _not_ working for the given example: `orphanRemoval` means to remove a child from a database, when its reference is removed, while `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` means to delete it, if the parent entity is deleted.

Comment: `orpahnRemoval` [means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621433/jpa-cascadetype-all-doesnt-delete-parent-and-child-rows) to delete the parent WITH its children. I think it should also work. What about the first solution?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/jpa-2-0-orphanremoval-true-vs-on-delete-cascade) would have been better to describe the difference between both annotations. But you are right, it would work - except that it does more than the op needed. I have nothing against your first solution - although I think the annotation is the better solution (see my comment on the op).

Comment: The question you linked in your comment explains the difference between JPA's `orphanRemoval` and `ON DELETE CASCADE` that is implemented on DB level (eg. [MySql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)). As I understand, OP needs to delete the parent along with its children, what `orphanRemoval` also does.